# unable to import csv table DATEs columns to BigQuery

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am unable to import csv table > DATEs columns to BigQuery,
DATEs are not recognized, even they have correct format according this docu
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect   YYYY-MM-DD

So DATEs columns are not recognized and are renamed to _2020-0122, 2020-01-23...
Is the issue that DATES are in 1st row as column name ?
But How can I then import dates, when I want use them in TimeSeries Charts (DataStudio) ?

here is sample source csv>

```
Province/State,Country/Region,Lat,Long,2020-01-22,2020-01-23,2020-01-24,2020-01-25,2020-01-026
Anhui,China,31.8257,117.2264,1,9,15,39,60
Beijing,China,40.1824,116.4142,14,22,36,41,68
Chongqing,China,30.0572,107.874,6,9,27,57,75
```

Here is ig from Bigquery
[image]

Comment: _"Is the issue that DATES are in 1st row as column name ?"_ - Yes. BigQuery is assuming that these are column headers, and not column values. You need to fix up your CSV file(s).

Comment: Excuse me, I am new in SQL, DB... Yes, this 1st row represent headers, but  for this particular columns also represent Date info or Timestamp when related Values was generated.My question is how to get all this data IN ?
Is only solution to create separate table for each Region/Country with Date column ? or is there any DB solution ?
So if I have 200 countries, I need 200 separate  tables to create manualy?

Comment: ... if I have already all data in this one csv

Answer (score 2):

If you have finite number of days, you can try unpivot table when using it. See [blog post.](https://yuhuisdatascienceblog.blogspot.com/2018/06/how-to-unpivot-table-in-bigquery.html)

otherwise, if you dont know how many day columns in csv file.
choose a unique character as csv delimiter then just load whole file into a single column staging table, then use [split](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split) function. you'll also need [unnest](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest). This approach requires a full scan and will be more expensive, especially when file gets bigger.

Comment: I have infinite number of days...its updating every day...OK, so another option is to have separate tables, right ? And  is there also  some option to connect related tables with uniq key (Country) ? e.g.1. table Timestamps 2nd table other stuff...if I want query other info..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in column names you cannot have a [date type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names), for this reason when the CSV is imported it takes the dates and transforms them to the format with underscores.

The first way to face the problem would be modifying the CSV file, because any import with the first row as a header will change the date format and then it will be harder to get to date type again. If you have any experience in any programming language you can do the transformation very easily. I can help doing this but I do not know your use case so maybe this is not possible. Where does this CSV come from?

If the CSV previous modification is not possible then the second option is what ktopcuoglu said, importing the whole file as one column and process this using SQL function. This is way harder than the first option and as you import all the data into a single column, all the data will have the same data type, what will be a headache too.

If you could explain where the CSV comes from we may be able to influence it before being ingested by BigQuery. Else, you'll need to deep into SQL a bit.

Hope it helps!

---

Hi, now I can help you further.

First I found some COVID datasets into the public bigquery datasets. The one you are taking from github [is already in BigQuery](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/johnshopkins/covid19_jhu_global_cases?_ga=2.121785995.-1201206137.1584215642), but there are many others that may work better for your task such as the one called “covid19_ecdc”, that is inside bigquery-public-data. This last one has the confirmed cases and deaths per date and country so it should be easy to make a time series.

Second, I found an interesting link performing what you meant with python and data studio. It’s a [kaggle discussion](https://www.kaggle.com/sudalairajkumar/novel-corona-virus-2019-dataset/discussion/135823) so you may not be familiar with it, but it deserves a check for sure . Moreover, he is using the dataset you are trying to use.

Hope it helps. Do not hesitate to ask!

Comment: Hi, here is the source https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv,
I would like to make  my own reports for education purpose.